# Fix Fonts in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

After installing and removing Kubuntu, some of the fonts in Chrome are showing up as times new roman instead of Ubuntu font. Is there any way to reset the fonts in Ubuntu and Chrome? I want to use the Ubuntu font everywhere.

[image]

[image]

[image]